# Error when deploying Tizen App - Failed to get a device information

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, television, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I am having a problem with deploying a Tizen app onto my Samsung smart tv. For some time it was working really good, but since updating tizen studio to 2.0 and the tv-extension to 4.0 it isn't working anymore. I always get a 'Failed to get a device information' error.

> [2017.11.22 00:54:29][ERROR] ProfileInfo.java(426) - Failed to get a device information from '10.0.0.40:26101' (model: UJ5500, platform: Tizen, version: unknown, profile: unknown                      `-¶) 
>   java.lang.Exception: Failed to get a device's profile version
>       at org.tizen.common.core.application.ProfileInfo.getProfileInfo(ProfileInfo.java:413)
>       at org.tizen.common.util.LaunchUtil.checkProfile(LaunchUtil.java:158)
>       at org.tizen.web.zimlaunch.deployer.ZimLaunchDelegate.preLaunchCheck(ZimLaunchDelegate.java:141)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:840)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

The required Tizen version is set to 2.3 and my model is a UJ5500 (2015).

On the dev website of samsung they say that this kind of error is only occuring on 2015 models and it can be ignored, but I can't deploy it. I also thought about downgrading tizen studio to 1.3 and the tv-extension to 3.0 as i had before, sadly I can't install the web-app dev of the package manager. For those of you who might think that this is caused by the certificate, I already created a public and partner one with my UDID of my Samsung device. And by the way it is also not working on an emulator (same error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sebastian, thank you for your help, but I already figured out what was wrong. In the tutorials and guides Samsung pointed to the Samsung certificates, but they are only working for some devices. I always got a PackageManager error in the cli. So I used a Tizen certificate. Then the app installed successfully on the TV.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use an older Tizen Studio for this (I know, I know, its stupid - hopefully you kept the old one around).  As I'm sure you've noticed you can't install the TV-2.3.0 extension that your TV requires.  I have the same problem with mine.  The answer is buried here: http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/specifications/tv-model-groups
and I got the inspiration to figure it out from: https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/sdk-ide/device-manager-unknown-platform?langredirect=1

Would be nice if they'd just let you install the older TV extensions in the new IDE right?  Oh well... hope this helps you a little.  If you are ever unsure run the undocumented "./sdb capability" and it'll show you what version the TV needs.

```
~/tizen-studio-2/tools/sdb capability

secure_protocol:enabled
rootcmd_support:disabled
zone_support:disabled
multiuser_support:disabled
cpu_arch:armv7
profile_name:tv
vendor_name:Samsung
--->>> platform_version:2.3.0 <<<---
product_version:1.0
sdbd_version:2.2.17
```

-Sebastian

Comment: Yeah I was already on this page. When i try to install an old extension rather than the 4.0 I can't install the web-app dev package. I always get an error.

Comment: Incase it's of help to anyone, you can find old versions of Tizen Studio here: http://download.tizen.org/sdk/Installer/

Answer (score 0):

I still believe you would want to revert to the older Tizen Studio so you could debug directly on the device.  I'm curious as to whether you still have full debugging capabilities using your method?