# Tizen TV - Deployment throws an error

Tags: java, tizen, tizen-web-app

When I try to install my package on my TV, I get this error.

```
C:\Temp\Tizen\tools>tizen install -n e:\systeminfo.wgt -t UE55KS7005

Transferring the package...
Transferred the package: E:\SystemInfo.wgt -> /opt/usr/apps/tmp
Installing the package...
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.tv.SecureCmdVer2_0_device
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.tv.TVSdbCmdSelector.<init>(TVSdbCmdSelector.java:32)
    at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.installPackage(InstallCLICommand.java:333)
    at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.call(InstallCLICommand.java:167)
    at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.call(InstallCLICommand.java:62)
    at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.AbstractSubCommand.runCommand(AbstractSubCommand.java:76)
    at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.InstallCLI.execute(InstallCLI.java:70)
    at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.AbstractCLI.execute(AbstractCLI.java:91)
    at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.run(Main.java:183)
    at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.main(Main.java:115)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.tv.SecureCmdVer2_0_device
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.tv.TVSdbCmdSelector.<init>(TVSdbCmdSelector.java:32)
    at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.getTVInstallCmd(InstallCLICommand.java:415)
    at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.installPackage(InstallCLICommand.java:348)
    at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.call(InstallCLICommand.java:167)
    at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.call(InstallCLICommand.java:62)
    at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.AbstractSubCommand.runCommand(AbstractSubCommand.java:76)
    at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.InstallCLI.execute(InstallCLI.java:70)
    at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.AbstractCLI.execute(AbstractCLI.java:91)
    at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.run(Main.java:183)
    at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.main(Main.java:115)
```

An error has occurred. See the log file tizen-sdk\tools\ide\cli.log.
Total time: 00:00:00.491

I cannot find the log it's referring to.

I have installed JRE, JDE, Tizen SDK and in Device Manager, I've hit "Permit to install applications".

The TV is a UE55KS7005

Any idea what is wrong?

Found the log file:

```
2018-08-27 20:56:07,424 [ERROR] Main.java(191) - 
2018-08-27 20:57:20,680 [TRACE] Main.java(127) - Start running Tizen CLI Main class...
2018-08-27 20:57:20,684 [TRACE] Main.java(128) - Argument count:7
2018-08-27 20:57:20,704 [TRACE] InstallCLI.java(59) - Execute InstallCLI...
2018-08-27 20:57:21,194 [ERROR] AbstractCLI.java(93) - 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.tv.TVSdbCmdSelector.getCmd(TVSdbCmdSelector.java:65)
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.getTVInstallCmd(InstallCLICommand.java:416)
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.installPackage(InstallCLICommand.java:348)
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.call(InstallCLICommand.java:167)
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.call(InstallCLICommand.java:62)
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.AbstractSubCommand.runCommand(AbstractSubCommand.java:76)
at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.InstallCLI.execute(InstallCLI.java:70)
at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.AbstractCLI.execute(AbstractCLI.java:91)
at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.run(Main.java:183)
at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.main(Main.java:115)
2018-08-27 20:57:21,196 [ERROR] Main.java(191) -
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with my Samsung Tizen 2016. When trying to install my application on the target `-t UE49KS7090`, I get the same Java Error with the `NullPointerException`.

Following log was created inside *cli.log*

```
2018-08-29 11:12:05,310 [ERROR] AbstractCLI.java(93) - 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.tv.TVSdbCmdSelector.getCmd(TVSdbCmdSelector.java:65)
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.getTVInstallCmd(InstallCLICommand.java:416)
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.installPackage(InstallCLICommand.java:348)
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.call(InstallCLICommand.java:167)
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.call(InstallCLICommand.java:62)
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.AbstractSubCommand.runCommand(AbstractSubCommand.java:76)
at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.InstallCLI.execute(InstallCLI.java:70)
at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.AbstractCLI.execute(AbstractCLI.java:91)
at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.run(Main.java:183)
at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.main(Main.java:115)
2018-08-29 11:12:05,312 [ERROR] Main.java(191) -
```

I ran `sdb connect <IP>` and then `tizen install -n my-application.wgt -- ./dist` (`-t` is only needed if there are multiple devices connected).

Furthermore when trying to install a package on a Tizen 2015 it raises an error with a `NumberFormatException` for input string `unk`.

```
Transferring the package...
Transferred the package: 
/my-hidden-path -> /opt/usr/apps/tmp
Installing the package...
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "unk" 
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043) 
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122) 
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451) 
at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:416) 
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.getTVInstallCmd(InstallCLICommand.java:423) 
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.installPackage(InstallCLICommand.java:348) 
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.call(InstallCLICommand.java:167) 
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.target.InstallCLICommand.call(InstallCLICommand.java:62) 
at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.AbstractSubCommand.runCommand(AbstractSubCommand.java:76) 
at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.InstallCLI.execute(InstallCLI.java:70) 
at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.AbstractCLI.execute(AbstractCLI.java:91)
at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.run(Main.java:183) 
at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.main(Main.java:115) 
Platform log view
Failed to install Tizen application.
Total time: 00:00:01.290
```

UPDATE:
Installing Tizen applications for 2015, 2016 and 2017 was successful using the `Java Version 8 Update 181` with `Tizen CLI Version 2.4.50`. But the problem described above following the prerequisites here (https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tizen-studio/download/installing-tizen-studio/prerequisites) still persists when installing the application on 2018.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.tv.SecureCmdVer2_0_device
```

Comment: I've got the same as you. It looks like 'unk' is a string parsing from the command line, and then a conversion from string to number is attempted, as can be seen a little above: at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451). I wonder if playing with the position of the options, this problem is gone.

Comment: Same problem here, but I don't think it is from the options. When I run the Device Manager from command line it shows the following: "Exception: cannot parse platform version for unknown´&á½X*á½À%¶-unknown¶`"

Comment: So it tries to convert the string "unknown" to a float. I actually could solve the problem by using my old MacBook 2013 with the Java version 1.8 Update 181 and install the application on Tizen 2015, 2016 and 2017. But it was not successful to install it on Tizen 2018 due to the error message: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't that be related with the fact that older TVs can't receive packages from newest Tizen SDKs. See answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47424846/error-when-deploying-tizen-app-failed-to-get-a-device-information). Try to install an older version of Tizen Studio or SDK from here http://download.tizen.org/sdk/Installer/

Comment: This might really be related but what needs to be done for 2018 devices?

Comment: Sorry can't share experience with a 2018 device.

I think UE55KS7005 from the original question is even older than 2015. I just faced this with a Tizen 2015 TV and moving to Tizen IDE 2.4 solved the issue. I also had to switch to Java 1.8.0.141 for this as the IDE would freeze with a too recent version of Java.